# SAML based SSO for SSRS 2016 Mobile reporting in Power BI app

Tags: reporting-services, oauth, saml, powerbi

I am investigating a scenario/set up where we want to host SSRS 2016 Mobile reports for one of our clients and provide SSO using SAML.

As it is known, SSRS 2016 Mobile reports are consumed in Power BI app and as per the recent updates to Power BI app, it now allows OAuth to connect to Reporting Services (2016). The standard set up to do so can be found on Power BI site,
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-mobile-oauth-ssrs/?mobileclient=ios

The above standard set up uses ADFS for user authentication when authenticating the user on Reporting Services (along with OAuth).

However, in our case, we would like to use SAML assertion over OAuth to provide authentication for Reporting Services as the Identity Provider is not in the same domain and is not something we have control over.

Does anyone have any experience/knowledge of if OAuth support for Reporting Services (SSRS 2016) will work with a SAML assertion from a separate Identity provider other than ADFS in the same domain as that of SSRS?

Is it correct to assume that in the above set up, we can simply replace the redirect URL to that of the third party Identity provider and it will simply show the login screen from the Identity provider to authenticate the user and pass the SAML token back to client to be used by SSRS?

There is a PoC available which uses SAML 2.0 Bearer Assertion Flow for OAuth 2.0 at the following location and I am not sure if this principle will work with SSRS 2016 Mobile reports in Power BI app?
http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/11/19/oauth2-with-saml2.html

Look forward to any help/advice on this.

Happy to share more details if any of the above is not clear.

Cheers,
Hitesh

Comment: Anyone interested in this functionality, it would help if you can vote for it in the Power BI Ideas forum, https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/30966808-saml-based-sso-for-ssrs-2016-mobile-reporting-in-p